# Updating data in ListVIew when Realm data changes

Tags: android, listview, react-native, realm

I am using Realm in a RN app that is set up like so:

```
this.classes = realm.objects('Notebook').sorted('active');
this.classes.addListener((name, changes) => {
        console.log("changed: " + JSON.stringify(changes));
        console.log("Number of items: " + this.classes.length);
});

var dataSource = new ListView.DataSource(
        {rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.name !== r2.name});

this.state = {
  dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.classes),
  src: dataSource
};
```

Everything is rendering fine initially. When I insert a new object like this:

```
realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('Notebook', {
        ...
    });
});
```

I get the notification in my listener that something has changed. However, what I see is:

> changed: {"deletions":[],"insertions":[],"modifications":[]}
>
> Number of items: 8

I would assume that there should be something listed in "insertions". Also, the number of items is always the number that existed before adding the new data. Can anyone tell me if I have something set up wrong?

Comment: Any reason not to use flatlist? By passing the `classes` straight to the data source there'd be no need to add a listener.

Comment: I want a listener so that I know when a class is added/deleted/updated and i can update my ListView accordingly.